# Printing out values with Javascript/AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a dropdown menu in PHP, Javascript en MySQL. I succesfully communicated with another PHP file through Javascript/AJAX. In the javascript, I'm sending an ID with the URL which I catch in the PHP file. In the PHP file I want to check what value the ID has, and then use it to check what query it should execute. Then I want to print those values out on each roll over. I think I'm alomost there, but I'm struck now.

The Javascript:

```
function onRollOver(id)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        test=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        test=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // document.getElementById('test').style.display="block";

    if (id == 1)
    {
        console.log("This is one"); 
    }
    else if (id == 2)
    {
        console.log("this i stwo");
    }
    console.log("id = " + id);

    test.open("GET","get_menu_id.php?id="+id,true);
    test.send();
}

function onRollOut()
{
    document.getElementById('test').style.display="none";
}
```

The PHP & HTML:

```
while($names = $get_category_names->fetch_object())
{
    $li_data = "<li data-dir=";

    //echo $li_data . $names->id . ">" . $names->name . "</li>";

    echo "<a onmouseover='onRollOver($names->id);' onmouseout='onRollOut($names->id);' >" . "$names->name" . "</a>"; 
}
```

The external PHP file:

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/constants.php");
require_once("../includes/connection.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");

$connect = connectDB();

//get the q parameter from URL
$id=$_GET["id"];

//lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
echo $id;

if ($id == 1)
{
    $nintendo = $connect->query("SELECT DISTINCT (categorypath) FROM feeds WHERE category_id = 1");

    while($names = $nintendo->fetch_object())
    {
        echo "<p>" . $names->categorypath . "</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Let us know what errors you're receiving, if any.

Comment: I haven't got any. It's just that I don't know how to print those values out of each query based on the ID to my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `onRollover` function after `test.send()`... `test.responseText` is going to contain the echo'd contents of your external php file. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with them.

Comment: When I console.log this value (test.responseText) it's giving an empty string, while the values are sent over the URL. 

I get this in firebug:

"(an empty string)
id = 1
GET get_menu_id.php?id=1
200 OK
45ms 
ParamsHeadersResponseHTML
ALOT OF VALUES HERE
(an empty string)"

Answer (score 0):

I would start by learning about [onreadystatechange, readyState, and responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest).